# RadChart Bar width

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight-4.0, telerik

I have a RadChart control. My goal is to make the data bar width fixed. I don't need to auto width the bars according to their numbers (I'm obviously using scrolling)

After searching the Telerik site and google I've come up with two articles. they both talk about the following line of code:

`RadChart1.PlotArea.XAxis.AutoScale`

The articles:

[The first article](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/chart/radchart-bar-width.aspx)

[The second article](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/reporting/telerik-reporting/rad-chart-x-axis-dynamic-width-and-bar-width-setting.aspx)

Actually I can't find the PlotArea property.. that would be because I have a newer version of Telerik?!!..... I don't know
Anybody knows an alternative property that does the same thing..?

Thanks

Note: I'm working on a Silverlight 4 web application

Answer (score 0):

You can use the BarWidthPercent Property of the StyleSeries class.  If you are configuring  your graph in XAML you will have to use the ItemWidthPercent property of the ChartArea.

```
 <telerik:RadChart Height="200" ItemsSource="{Binding ChartData, Mode=OneWay}"  >
            <telerik:RadChart.DefaultView>
                <telerik:ChartDefaultView>
                    <telerik:ChartDefaultView.ChartArea>
                        <telerik:ChartArea ItemWidthPercent="10">
```

The AutoScale property you are referring to is the setting for the xaxis scales its min and max values.